# Android an activity variable

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

Colleagues, I have a strategic question.

I have MainActivity where I initialize a new Connection class :

```
Connection connection=new Connection(MainActivity.this);
```

Then in the connection class constructor  I started a fragment:

```
public class Connection {

 private Context context;

 public Connection(Activity context) {

 this.context = context; 

 context.showFragment(…);

 }
}
```

Besides I initialize the context variable.

After I start a fragment  I’ll use  this context variable in Connection class because the Connection class  helps the fragment interacting with  a remote server.

And I suppose this scheme (especially the context variable) can give subtle errors? Or is it right scheme?

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. Every `Fragment` is tightly coupled to an `Activity`. Use `getActivity()` to get a reference for your operation.

Comment: constructor argument should be `Context context` as you are passing `MainActivity.this` in constructor

Comment: Murat K. This makes sense. The scheme allows to make the code more readable and flexible (use the principles of OOP), as you need to run a lot of different fragments from the activiti, and every fragment has a  lot of tasks, tasks are carried in other classes.

Comment: Dhruvam Gupta, yes. You are right it's context not activity; I'm sorry for the mistake